# Ambiguous reference to member in API testing

Tags: swift, rest, unit-testing

I'm trying to learn `Unit Testing`. For that, I want to test a response from an API. 
here is my code

```
func testAPIworking(){
        guard let url = URL(string: profileUrlstring) else {fatalError()}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                XCTFail("Fail")
            }
            expectation.fulfill() //I got an error here
        }
        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 20)
    }
```

but I got this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'expectation(description:)'
>   in the line of

```
expectation.fulfill()
```

could anyone help me that where is my problem here?
Many thanks

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: I need your help.

Comment: Is your container class inheriting from XCTestCase() ?
Did you declare let expectation = expectation()